# How to dynamically pass service account to Cloud Build config?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I was trying to parametrize service account in Cloud Build configuration:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    args: [ 'gcloud', '--help']
substitutions:
  _SERVICE_ACCOUNT: my-service-account@developer.gserviceaccount.com
serviceAccount: 'projects/$PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/${_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}'
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

but this returns error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: could not parse service account URL
```

So, I guess, custom substitutions are not supported in the service account field.
If this is the case, what is a recommended way to reuse cloud build configuration with different service accounts?

Comment: @JohnHanley it works if I use value without substitution for serviceAccount field and without the **--impersonate-service-account** flag. As in this [guide from documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts#running_builds_from_the_command_line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my deep understanding of Cloud build, it can't work.

Think about the architecture. When you start your Cloud Build instance, you have to load all the Google Cloud standard context, such as the metadata server. the metadata server serves the credentials and it must be known when the instance starts.

The substitution variable are interpreted at runtime, so after the instance start.

---

Therefore, you can't interpret the service account email with a substitution variable before the instance start, but only after. But after, it's too late to load the correct service account in the metadata server.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense! What confuses me is that $PROJECT_ID is being substituted. I mean when I use `projects/$PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/my-service-account@developer.gserviceaccount.com` it works. Does it mean that $PROJECT_ID is substituted on the earlier stage and custom substitutions at runtime?

Comment: @OleksandrBushkovskyi Precisely, it's already done just that when you first start running it. `$PROJECT_ID` is one of the defaults, so it'll likely use the project you're running it on or the one you've declared using [`gcloud config set`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) (assuming you've not set it in an earlier step yourself)